# Prevent admin account from logging-in via WooCommerce Login Page

Tags: authentication, woocommerce, hardening

I am trying to harden the best I can admin access to a WordPress site with WooCommerce.

So far I managed to do the following:

- whitelist the admin access from a specific IP in .htaccess with:

  ```
  <Files wp-login.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 123.123.123.123
  </Files>
  ```
- allow WooCommerce customers to login via WooCommerce login page (example.com/my-account)

I have two problems however:

1. Admin is still able to login from WooCommerce login page *example.com/my-account* and I would like to avoid that (as it makes the above .htacess rule useless)
2. When customers are trying to logout, they get `403 Forbidden` (I guess it's due to the above .htaccess rule)

So I was wondering has anybody managed to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?